# How can we get message body with specified name in XMPP Framework IOS?

Tags: android, ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I am making IM app and while coding I found a problem or may be because I am beginner so I am not able to resolve this.

```
<message to="aaa@example.com">
<body>abc</body>
<body xml:lang="secret">xyz</body>
</message>
```

in android I can get this by using asmack built in functions `message.getBody("secret")`

But don't know how to do it in iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the type of the message is XMPPMessage you do the following

```
NSString *body = [message bodyForLanguage:@"secret"];
```

or you could try the folowing

```
NSArray *bodies = [message elementsForName:@"body"]
NSXMLElement *theBody;
for (NSXMLElement *b in bodies) {
  if ([@"secret" isEqualToString:[b attributeForName:@"xml:lang"]]) {
    theBody = b;
  }
}
```